# ToolBar is not in correct size after adding buttons in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx

I want to add buttons with just an image, i.e. without any text, just iconified button.

This is a class of my button:

```
package custom.toolbar;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;

class MyButton extends Button {

    MyButton() {
        getStyleClass().add("my-button");
        setMinSize(25, 25);
        setMaxSize(25, 25);
    }
}
```

And I have created custom toolbar that derives JavaFX ToolBar.

```
package custom.toolbar;

import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;

class MyToolBar extends ToolBar {

    MyToolBar() {
        getStyleClass().add("my-toolbar");
    }
}
```

CSS file as well:

```
.my-button {
    -fx-background-image: url("../img/icon/open.png");
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-position: center;
    -fx-background-size: 16px 16px;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.my-button:hover {
    -fx-border-color: lightgray;
    -fx-background-color: #ededed;
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
    -fx-border-radius: 2px;
}

.my-toolbar {
    -fx-background-color: lightcyan;
}
```

And finally Main class itself:

```
package custom.toolbar;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        anchorPane.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        anchorPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white");

        MyToolBar myToolBar = new MyToolBar();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            myToolBar.getItems().add(new MyButton());

        anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(myToolBar);

        String styleCss = getClass().getResource("/css/my-toolbar.css").toExternalForm();

        Scene scene = new Scene(anchorPane);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(styleCss);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I am adding 5 buttons on ToolBar. ToolBar's color is lightcyan, this is because I just wanted to highlight so to see the size of the ToolBar.

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

As you see the size of the ToolBar is smaller then the size of the all buttons with insets altogether. And I don't know why padding is not working in AnchorPane.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the size of `MyToolBar` add the PreferedSize to `MyButton`

```
class MyButton extends Button {
    MyButton() {
        getStyleClass().add("my-button");
        setPrefSize(25, 25);
        setMinSize(25, 25);
        setMaxSize(25, 25);
    }
}
```

The padding only works in the `AnchorPane` if you anchored the nodes.

For example:

```
AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
anchorPane.setPadding(new Insets(20));

MyToolBar myToolBar = new MyToolBar();
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(myToolBar, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(myToolBar, 0.0);

anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(myToolBar);
```